# apex 5.0.1 and css class for HTML button

Tags: oracle-apex-5

- in apex 4.2.3 i can add class to my button using

  Button style : HTML button

  Button CSS Classes : myclass
- in apex 5

  Button style is changed by Button template (HTML button (legacy - APEX5 migration)

==> Where can i put my button css class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS Classes is hidden by default to display it we have to do one of the two things

1- click on Show all
[image]

2- click on "Go to group" then "Appearance"